# Gremlin groovy to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, groovy, graphql, gremlin, janusgraph

I'm using [Gremlin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gremlin) (JS library) to communicate with JanusGraph. I have the following groovy code which works well in the groovy console:

```
g.V().project('id', 'data').by(id).by(valueMap('value').by(unfold()))
```

But when I copy this code to JS it says that id, valueMap, and unfold are undefined. How can I rewrite the groovy code to valid JS?

---

**EDIT**

I know I can use the client and submit the query as shown below, but that's inconvenient given the fact that we already have, I suppose, a fully working JS library.

```
const c = new driver.Client('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin');
const q = `
      g.V()
        .project('id', 'data')
        .by(id)
        .by(
          valueMap('value')
            .by(unfold())
        )
    `;

return await c.submit(q);
```

Comment: Please also see: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_common_imports_2

Comment: @stephenmallette What about the undefined id tho?

Comment: Oooh now I see.. it's __.id(). Thank you!

Comment: or better `T.id`